# How to interchange the lines in the section of the webform tables in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal

I am looking solution for task.
In the results of the table, I need to make the order of the rows in the webforms Drupal 7. 
For example:
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve. You want to allow ordering by those 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that page is a view. Hover it with a mouse (assuming you are logged in as an admin, of course) and gear icon will appear at upper right corner. Click it and click "edit view" link. You'll end up at that view edit page.

Now at "Format" section click "Settings" link. Here you'll see table with all the fields and for those you want to make sortable check checkbox at "Sortable" column and clik "Apply" button. After that you have to save a view you just edited (Save button will appear when view is changed).